# Combine with Relation with where sentence in Laravel8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm learning Laravel's `relations`. I'm having problems with the 2nd line.

I would like to display records that `Auth::user` table's `br_name column = Partner table's br_name column` matches.

Could you teach me the right code please?

UPDATE

```
  public function mybr()
    {
        $blogs = Blog::with('user','category','partner')
            ->where('App\Partner::partner()->br', Auth::user()->br_name)//I'm having problem this line
            ->where(function($query){
                $query->where('status', '=','new');
                ->orWhere('status', '=', 'old');
                     })->paginate(250);

        return view('blogs.mybr')->with('blogs',$blogs);
    }
```

Comment: Replace `->where('App\Partner::partner()->br', Auth::user()->br_name)` by `->whereHas('partner', function ($query) { $query->where('br', auth()->user()->br_name); })`
@bluetail

Comment: First param of `where()` must be column name, not an executable phrase

Comment: What does `App\Partner::partner()->br` return? Edit your question and share your `App\Partner` class.

Comment: @Thanh Dao Thank you very much! It worked!. I see that where() must be column name I learned alot.

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa Thank you very much for helping me.  I used Mr Thanh Dao code and solved problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code, and I have done some query refactoring too.

Like I have used `whereIn`

```php
$blogs = Blog::with(['user','category','partner' => function ($query) {
             $query->where('br', '=', Auth::user()->br_name);
         }])->whereIn('status',['new','old'])
        ->paginate(250);
```

Comment: Thank you for responded me. I think my explain was bad Actually I'm having problem this part  'App\Partner::partner()->br'  .  Seems like this is wrong...but I don't know how to fix.

Comment: Dear @oreopot I update my whole code. Could you take a look please?

Comment: @bluetail could you please add your `App\partner` model too?

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me.  I used Mr Thanh Dao code and solved problem. Thank you..